# Creating a boolean for Tic Tac Toe Java GUI to tell if the player wins

Tags: java, boolean, logic

I am new to programming and have been trying to make a GUI tic tac toe game. For will be showing a dumb down program of mine in which the four buttons are clicked, it will print either 'X' or 'Y'.I am able to change btw 'X' and 'Y' for my GUI game whenever a button is clicked. However, I've been working at creating a char array to detect whether the player has won or not.

```
 class Board extends JPanel{

    // char[][] cells = new char[2][2];
    //boolean won(char token)....?
    //any clue to construct a boolean to tell if cells[0][0] === cels[0][1]?

    private char token = ' ';
    char turn = 'O';
    char getToken(){
        return token;
    }

    void setToken(char token){
        this.token = token;
    }


    JButton b[] = new JButton[4];

    public Board(){
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,0,0));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++){
            b[i] = new JButton();
            add(b[i]);
        }
        listener();

    }
    void listener(){

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i ++){
            b[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                turn = (turn == 'X') ? 'O': 'X';

                System.out.println("Button Clicked" + turn);
          //add if(won(turn))....?

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: How do you run your code (there's no `main()`)

Comment: `public void answer() { yourQuestion.wait(); }`

Comment: Need a boolean to detect if(cell[i][j] == cell[i][j]), that player wins.

Comment: -- alfasin : I would have copy and paste too much. This is a board that I will add to my main.

Answer (score 0):

By the code, I guess that you are creating a 3X3 square with buttons and a char matrix.
So for to check if the player wins you will need check

lines

```
[0][0] == [0][1] == [0][2] OR
[1][0] == [1][1] == [1][2] OR
[2][0] == [2][1] == [2][2]
```

columns

```
[0][0] == [1][0] == [2][0] OR
[0][1] == [1][1] == [2][1] OR
[0][2] == [1][2] == [2][2]
```

diagonals

```
[0][0] == [1][1] == [2][2] OR
[0][2] == [1][1] == [2][0]
```

PS: OR = ||

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonas Mayer.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to structure a better action listener?